# Error with the Ask Ubuntu data dump

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, data-dump

It seems like there is a problem with the [Ask Ubuntu data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/creative-commons-data-dump-nov-10/).

One of the questions ([this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10647/auto-starting-a-program-before-any-other-program-and-preventing-it-to-run-the-oth)), has an answer posted *after* the end of the month. This answer is not included in the dump, as expected.

**However,** the entry for that question:

```
<row ... AnswerCount="1" ... />
```

As you can see, it indicates that the question has **1 answer**, which it really doesn't.

Comment: It's gotta be hard to make an accurate snapshot of a live database...

Comment: If you're including the answers, it's not that hard to count them.

Comment: @Hans: It may be hard on the database implementer, but any serious database has this feature (either completely built-in or relying on host OS features). It's necessary for backups, for instance.

Comment: Can someone please explain *why* this is 'status-bydesign'?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the answer didn't exist when the answers were written to the post, but existed when the `AnswerCount` was written.

Comment: Probably... I'm guessing that's what happened.